# Is it possible to compute all the values at the same time when writing a script?

Tags: matlab

When defining a function, say `TEST = @(t) t.^2`. If the input is a vector, say `[1,2,3,4]`, `TEST([1,2,3,4]) = [1,4,9,16]`.

Can we do similar thing if the function defined is in script form? What I mean is that if I have a script, say TEST.m such that `ret = TEST(x,y,z)` which outputs a value when knowing numerical values of `x`, `y` and `z`. Suppose I want to calculate 100 different values of `z` ranging from 1 to 100 when `x`, `y` are fixed, say at 0, 1 respectively. Is it possible to output `TEST(0,1,1:1:100)` without writing a for loop or changing any contents of the script TEST.m?

The reason to ask such question comes from the computation time. Usually, the script I have may be a little complicated so that the calculate of a single value may take few minutes to go. Writing for-loop to output it can be very time-consuming. I think of writing `parfor` loop, but the computation time is still long to me for further uses. I wonder if I can calculate all the 100 values at a time. I am a starter of programmer, and I hope I can get satisfactory answers after this post. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It depends on how `TEST` is computing values but for most cases, the answer is yes.  Please provide an example calculation of how `x`, `y` and `z` are to be used. kthxbye.

Comment: In general, the function inside TEST are not simple to be expressed. For simplicity, assume that the script TEST.m is defined as
function ret=TEST(x,y,z)
ret=f(x,y,z)
f may be chosen as x^3+y^2+z^4 for simplicity. Remember in general, the function can be very complicated. Note that if you pass x,y,z for specific value, you get an answer.
My point is no change about the structure in the script. Try not to rewrite the function to be x.^3+y.^2+z.^4, allowing the input of a vector.

Comment: I write in another script calling the TEST.m. My ultimate goal is to obtain numerical values of TEST(0,1,1:1:100) for example without writing a for loop.

Comment: If `TEST` is working element-wise on `x,y,z`, like: `function ret = TEST(x,y,z)
    ret = x.^3+y.^2+z.^4; end` you can just use it with a vector in in `z` (though if you use more than one vector, say `x` and `z`, they have to be the same length). 
If not, you have to provide some minimal example to be discussed.

Comment: It is very difficult to provide the function inside the TEST.m. In my work, the function in TEST.m involves the calculation of several different integrals or even complicated maths based on the input, which cannot be written as explicit formula like the form x.^3+y.^2+z.^4.
For simplicity, you may treat ret=TEST(x,y,z)=f(x)+g(y)+h(z). The point here is f, g and h are three different functions which accept numerical values only, i.e. f(1), f(2) can be computed but f([0,1]) cannot. What I need is to fix x, y at some chosen points (say (0,1)) with z varying from 1 to 100.

Comment: The answer is yes.  You need to write `f`, `g` and `h` to accept vectors.  If they accept only scalar values you can use `arrayfun` but that is just a wrapper around a loop.  The correct solution is to write `f`, `g` and `h` correctly.  A vector of length 1 is still a valid vector.

Answer (score 0):

You cab define a new anonymous function to get the fixed values as parameters, and the vector as input. Then use `arrayfun` to compute it on all values of the array.

Say you have this functions:

```
function ret = TEST(x,y,z)
    ret = f(x)+g(y)+h(z);
end

function r = f(x)
r = x^2;
end

function r = g(y)
r = y^3;
end

function r = h(z)
r = z^4;
end
```

And you call it from:

```
x = 2;
y = 3;
z = 1:5;
T = @(z) TEST(x,y,z);
arrayfun(T,z)
```

So `T` is a new function that treat `x` and `y` as constants, and only have `z` as input. Then `arrayfun` takes `T` and compute it for every element in `z`, and you get:

```
ans =

    32    47   112   287   656
```

Now, you can use `arrayfun` with more vectors, like `[a,b,c] = arrayfun(T,z,w,v)`, if `x` and `y` can stay constant.

Hopes it answers your question ;)

Comment: @will_cheuk did this solve your problem? If not, why?