# How to evaluate the following integrals for different values?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I want to compute the following definite integral with integrand as follow:
`J A(u)B(u)`, say lower limit to be 0 and upper limit to be `T`. Here `J` is a row vector `[1 1 1]`, `A(u)` is a square matrix and `B(u)` is another column vector. `A(u)`, for example, takes the following form `diag([f_1(u) f_2(u) f_3(u)]) A diag([f_1(u) f_2(u) f_3(u)])`. `B(u)` is a column vector say `[g_1(u);g_2(u);g_3(u)]'`.

What I want is that when I input `T` to be a vector, say `[1:1:100]`, I can get 100 definite integral values. Are there any good ways to do the problems? For simplicity, `f_1`, `f_2`, `f_3` and `g_1`, `g_2`, `g_3` can be treated as piece-wise constant function.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448933/is-it-possible-to-compute-all-the-values-at-the-same-time-when-writing-a-script/38462468#38462468) answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has a number of ways to numerically evaluate definite integrals:

- [`quad`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quad.html),
- [`quadgk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html),
- [`quadv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadv.html),
- [`quadl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadl.html), etc.

All these techniques are specific ways of doing *quadrature integration*. Some work well for oscillating integrals, some for infinite limits, etc. I usually try all of them before deciding which one works best for a given problem .

Once you implement your integrand `J * A(u) * B(u)` as a function, you can call any of these quadrature functions with that function handle, and the limits, to get a *single* definite integral.

Then, once you have an expression for a single definite integral, you can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) as @EBH mentioned to evaluate the definite integral over a *range* of upper limits.

If you specify what `f_1` etc. are, we can help you write some elegant code to do this.